# Query that return city name and how many records exists in that city?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a project in C#. In my database I have a table "Users" in which there is a field "City". Now I want to put some query that returns all the cities and how many users belongs to that city. For example there are 9 users in that table and 3 users live in New York, 3 in Chicago and 3 in Washington so the output should be: 
City- New York, Records- 3 
etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide sample data for your homework and show your query so someone can fix it.

Comment: Have you attempted to construct a query to this end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by city and then get the count of cities.

```
select City, count(City) as Records
from Users
group by City
```